# How do I get the value of an ASCII code in Java?

Tags: java, ascii

I am trying to return an array of values from a string of values. However, my code returns the ASCII code values of the string that has been inputted. Here is my code, a test case, and what it currently returns.

```
public static int[] stringToBigInt(String s) {
    int []A = new int [SIZE];

    int j = s.length() - 1;
    for (int i = A.length - 1; j >= 0 && i >= 0; --i){
        A[i] = s.charAt(j);
        --j;
    }

    return A;   
}

    System.out.println("Test 8: Should be\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2]");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString( stringToBigInt( "3141592" ) ));
    System.out.println();
```

Run:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 51, 49, 52, 49, 53, 57, 50]

Comment: Take a look at an ASCII table: `'3'` is `51`, `'1'` is `49`, etc...

Comment: `int` is not `char`. put your chars in a char[], not an int[]

Comment: Side note: `int a[]` is the Java way of declaring an array.

Comment: (also, `String.toCharArray`, instead of complicated loops)

Comment: @MarounMaroun that's the other way around

Comment: @njzk2 So that C programmers don't feel bad :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way:

Just subtract the char with the '0' char.

```
public static int[] stringToBigInt(String s) {
        int []A = new int [SIZE];

        int j = s.length() - 1;
        for (int i = A.length - 1; j >= 0 && i >= 0; --i){
            A[i] = s.charAt(j) - '0';
            --j;
        }

        return A;   
    }
```

Output is:

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2]

Comment: Quite a creative idea!

Comment: @RobertColumbia Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code:

```
public class Test {
    private static final int SIZE = 20;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test 8: Should be\n[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2]");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringToBigInt("3141592")));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int[] stringToBigInt(final String s) {
        int[] A = new int[SIZE];

        int j = s.length() - 1;
        for(int i = A.length - 1; j >= 0 && i >= 0; --i) {
            A[i] = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(j));
            --j;
        }

        return A;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use [Integer.parseInt](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-string-to-int/), and Character.toString as @NeilLocketz mentioned. Your array `A` is an array of `int`, so you need to get the underlying integer *values* of the characters you are reading.

```
for (int i = A.length - 1; j >= 0 && i >= 0; --i){
    A[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(s.charAt(j)));
    --j;
}
```